# geoserver preview error when output format is openlayers and png

Tags: gis, geoserver

After I imported shapefiles into geoserver following a tutorial  and tried to preview, I find the output image is not right while there is no errors in logs when i choose openlayers or png, jpeg, gif. The image is like a map stained by ink.

However, when I output the layer as PDF, the image is normal ....

All the configurations are default except SRS.

The url is 
    http://localhost:7070/geoserver/mygis/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=mygis:roads&styles=&bbox=1.2878111774224255E7,4781149.089993679,1.3037623853023177E7,4928041.91732644&width=768&height=707&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

And the tiled layer of my imported shapefiles is blank.

Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing the map and some more information about the shapefile it is hard to give a definitive answer but looking at the URL you provide the problem seems to be that you have specified the SRS (projection) as EPSG:4326 which is lat/lon degrees while your bounding box appears to be measured in meters which means that all your data will be clustered in the very centre of the map if it really is in degrees or distorted due to the mismatch in projections if it is projected.

As a first guess I would change the SRS parameter to epsg:3875 (web mercator) and see if it looks better.

Comment: The error image is similar with this question [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11806/geoserver-image-generation-error) . The difference is that half of my image is broken.I don't know if the SRS is the problem because the pdf format is normal. And I can render the same shapefiles by Mapnik and MapServer normally with same parameters. So... that's strange.....